# Let JDBI map the results for a custom query

Tags: java, jdbi

I want to make a complicated query, and let JDBI handle the result mapping. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
interface MyDao {
  @MapResultAsBean @SqlQuery("hardcoded query with :arg here")
  ResultDto query(@Bind("arg") String arg);
}
ResultDto result = dbi.open(MyDao.class).query(arg);
```

Since the query is generated at runtime, I cannot do this, but I still want to use the result set mapping features. I've tried using the Handle interface:

```
String query = generateCustomQuery();
ResultDto result = dbi.open().createQuery(query).mapTo(ResultDto.class).first();
```

but I don't see a way to pass the `arg`. I could string-concat it into the generated query, but I'd rather pass it as if using `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to make use of [`bind`](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/SQLStatement.html#bind(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

```
dbi.open().createQuery(query).mapTo(ResultDto.class).bind(":arg", "value").first();
```